# offline web application doesn't work in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, caching, offline-caching

I use `cache.manifest` (with correct content-type and expire=-1 http-header) to cache a very very simple page for offline use. ([this page](http://aladmin.ir/offline-test/))

The page works correctly with chrome browser, but FF 29 doesn't display it when I am offline.

I also use [this code](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache) but I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: have you added `manifest="cache.manifest">` to your `<html>` tag?

Comment: i link to the page at my question. you can see the page and test it.

Comment: On Chrome it seems to work, but not on FF. The answers to this question are clarifying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303785/html5-cache-manifest-working-great-on-chrome-but-not-on-firefox-and-opera, maybe you are facing the same issue?

Comment: i saw the answer... i finally believe that Firefox has problem in caching offline globally not only for my page. other demo of HTML5 offline application doesn't work for me in Firefox too.